# Is there anyway to manipulate the data of an intent on android?

Tags: java, android, cordova, streaming

For example, I create an intent with the action to record a video like so:

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

Now this will open up the camera preview and allow the user to capture video, my question is, is the data accessible during the action. For example, can I take the stream of the video being recorded while it's being recorded and push the data to a server. So once the video has finished recording it is already on the server, and during the push the data can be encoded on the server etc...

I'm doing this using Apache Cordova 2.2.0, so my code actually looks more like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, 2);
```

I did try adding an MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, but this I'm sure saves it to the output location after the recording is complete.

Is there a way I can asynchronously find the location the video is being recorded to and work with the incomplete stream from within the android file system?

So I guess to simplify my question without throwing anyone off, is it possible to do anything with the intent data during the activity?

Answer (score 3):

> is the data accessible during the action

At best, that will be dependent upon the app that is performing the action.

> Is there a way I can asynchronously find the location the video is being recorded to and work with the incomplete stream from within the android file system?

Write your own video recorder, using `MediaRecorder`.

> is it possible to do anything with the intent data during the activity?

If you did not write the activity, there are no guarantees as to what is or is not possible until `onActivityResult()` is called.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I think I'm going to go with writing my own video recorder, do you know if there is a good example anywhere? I figured I would write my own Intent based off the ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and see how they did that and just add in code to record the video to a server versus to the sdcard.

Comment: @theprestig3: "I think I'm going to go with writing my own video recorder, do you know if there is a good example anywhere?" -- probably there is, but I don't have one personally, nor do I know where to point you. Getting into video recording (and bringing my old still camera stuff back to life) is on the docket for the first half of 2013 for me. "and just add in code to record the video to a server versus to the sdcard" -- that will be tricky, as `MediaRecorder` definitely wants files, at least for audio. Headers need to be rewritten on file close, and so on.